# Xcode 4: Why can't I add a header file to a unit test target?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

I have a basic Cocoa project open in Xcode including a unit test target.

I created a new test class to test one of my model classes. However, I can't add the header of the class I need to test to the unit testing target. The checkbox under "Target Membership" is not clickable for the unit test target (it is for the main target).

Because I can't add the header file to the unit test target, Xcode won't autosuggest method names of the class under test.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't I be able to add header files to a unit testing target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Xcode expert, but in my project, none of the header files have any target memberships set, none of the checkboxes are clickable - you can only add the .m files, and header files are somehow magically included. You should be able to just import the header file at the top of the test file and have method autocomplete work - unless you're using some weird macros in those tests, because I've noticed that Xcode gets confused with autocomplete while you're inside a macro call. If that's the case, try if the autocomplete works outside any macros.

Comment: Xcode doesn't even resolve the unit test macros (e.g. STAssertEquals) if I Command-click on them (but the code compiles and runs). Not sure what is wrong with the project. Maybe there's a mixed up build setting somewhere

Comment: If it compiles then it's a problem with autocomplete itself, not with something not being included properly in the build, otherwise it wouldn't compile. Xcode's autocomplete breaks quite often for me - sometimes it's because of a syntax error, sometimes it's because the cursor is inside a macro, and sometimes I just close the project and reopen it and then it works again...

Comment: That's strange because my project in XCode 8 builds correctly only if I specify my default target fro my .hpp files (programming C++), but for unknown reason checkbox for Test target is disabled and I cannot make my unit tests see declarations of my mocked classes in hpp files.